# MySQL replace multiple character

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to fetch data from my MySQL database where one column is filled with strings that contains different quotes and apostrophes (*‘, ’, ` and the classic one '*).

In my search bar, I want to be able to only write the classic one ' and be able to search for that specific field wheter it contains ‘, ’ or `.
For example, I'd like to write "***Regie de l'Angleterre***" and that it automatically checks "***Regie de l‘Angleterre***" and so on.

Is that possible ?

How can I do something like this in SQL ? I tried to use REPLACE, but couldn't make it work with multiple

My where clause looks like this at the moment.

```
SELECT realestate_name FROM realestates WHERE REPLACE(realestate_name, ''','\'') LIKE %xxx%
```

Comment: I recommend using a LIKE statement if your database isn't too huge. I posted my answer below, it should work for you. You will need to use a replace function in whatever code you use (before MySQL) to replace all the different quotation marks & spaces with % percent symbols % for the LIKE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT realestate_name FROM realestates WHERE column LIKE '____'
```

Before you do that, change every single ' " ` and quotation mark and space to %, and put them on the ends

So it would look like this:

Regie de l‘Angleterre becomes: %Regie%de%l%Angleterre%

```
SELECT realestate_name FROM realestates WHERE realestate_name LIKE %Regie%de%l%Angleterre%
```

This will work & run fine with a not so large database. If you have millions of records, LIKE becomes a nightmare.

Comment: Why use % for one symbol use _ instead.

Comment: I wrote it like that to account for records with extra spaces, wrong spelling, etc. You're right though, an underscore is better if he knows for a fact that all of the records are simply using different quotation types.

Comment: I did exactly what you did, replacing the % by _ like @dimoraichev said, and that's perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple replaces in one `select` the Replace function returns `string` so you can call another one outside it. Like this

```
SELECT 
realestate_name 
FROM realestates 
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(realestate_name, ''','\''),'’','\'')  LIKE %xxx%
```